# hibernate usage should have dbmanager?

Tags: java, hibernate

In hibernate usage, should there be a db manager that all DAO's  would use?
or should all the daos extends an abstract DAO that would provide the db access?

Answer (score 0):

with hibernate DB access is provided by a class called SessionFactory, there is usually 1 sessionfatory per application (per database).

Its always better to have one base dao which has most common operations (CRUD) & other dao's extend it addition functionality as required.

if you are using spring then you have a class called `HibernateDaoSupport` this class provides a template which simplifies all the dataaccess (dbconnection, basically Sessionfactory, session).

-Anantha Sharma

Comment: yes but my question is why should this Sessionfactory be accessed from a base class of my dao, rather than creating a util which my dao will use?

Comment: you can use a util, there is no problem with it.. the idea behind keeping the session & sessionfactory in dao classes is to avoid the use of these components directly from service layer ( abstraction ) the service layer will make calls to DAO without any knowledge as to what is used to get the data...